# How to create a multiline entry with tkinter?

Tags: python, input, tkinter, multiline

`Entry` widgets seem only to deal with single line text. I need a multiline entry field to type in email messages.

Anyone has any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 27):

You could use the [Text](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/morewidgets.html#text) widget:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Or with scrolling bars using [ScrolledText](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = Tk()
ScrolledText(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I *highly* recommend *not* importing everything from Tkinter. IMO you should use `import Tkinter as tk; tk.Tk()...`. It makes your code more self-documenting and immune to problems caused by importing other libraries that have functions with the same name as the Tkinter widgets (for example, ttk and tk both have classes named `Button`)

Comment: @BryanOakley I completely agree and admit that my answer was done in haste. Thanks for the edit. I haven't updated the code so your comment will stand but am happy to do so if you think it's worthwhile.

Comment: Is there a way to use a stylable widget to achieve the same result? The `Text` Widget seems to not be available in ttk.

Comment: @Zephir You can always import both, as such: `from tkinter import *, from tkinter import ttk`, since * doesn't include ttk by default.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Text()` widget.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

> [image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/discussions/1821). I based it on a tutorial that I found.

It might need some extra work, depending on you requirements, but it's a good start and it is based on TreeView, but allows in-place edits.

You would just need to strip out a few CustomTkinter lines if you want to work in pure Tkinter.