# Python Tkinter ScrolledText

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter entry box, but need more space than just one line. It seems that

```
self.scroll = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self.tk).pack()
```

is the best looking way to do it right now, but I dont know how to get the inputted text from self.scroll and use it for something else, theres no clear documentation on it either. Does anyone know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a multiline entry with tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661854/how-to-create-a-multiline-entry-with-tkinter)

Comment: The question and answers can use syntax that is more readable as follows: `from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText` Then you can use the `ScrolledText` class readily (instead of typing `ScrolledText.ScrolledText`).

Answer (score 13):

Mistake:

```
self.scroll = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self.tk).pack()
```

this way you assign `pack()` result to `self.scroll` (not `ScrolledText`)
and `pack()` always returns `None`.

Always:

```
self.scroll = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self.tk)
self.scroll.pack()
```

And now see standard [Text Widget](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/text.htm) documentation how to get/set text.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledtext as ScrolledText

master = Tk()

st = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(master)
st.pack()

st.insert(INSERT, "Some text")
st.insert(END, " in ScrolledText")

print(st.get(1.0, END))

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have mutliple lines by tweaking the **height** parameter:

```
sText = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(root, height=15)
sText.pack()
```

Get the content using:

```
words = sText.get(1.0,END)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

To get the inputted text from within a [`Scrolltext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html#module-tkinter.scrolledtext) widget in tkinter, the same `get` method is used as that of the `Text` widget([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014280/tkinter-how-can-you-use-get-to-save-the-input-in-a-scrolled-text-widget-to-a)). The two parameters of the function are the START and the END of the text extraction. In your use case, it seems you want to fetch the entire text which can be done by extracting text from line index "1.0" to `tkinter.END`, which is a constant that always points to the last line index.(for more info on line indices see [this](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html).)

get method syntax -:

```
widget.get("1.0", tkinter.END)
```

In your case it will become -:

```
self.scroll.get("1.0", tkinter.END)
```

---

Further, as pointed out by @furas, the `pack` method should be called separately as pack returns `None`, for more info refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name). Fixed code for that section will be -:

```
self.scroll = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self.tk)
self.scroll.pack()
```