# tkinter - How can you use get() to save the input in a Scrolled Text widget to a variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The following code works for Entry(), but when I use ScrolledText() it fails to work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

def click():
    a = text1.get()
    print(a)

window = Tk()
window.title("TITLE PLACEHOLDER")
Label(window,text="Subject", bg="black",fg="white", font="Arial 10").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
text1 = ScrolledText(window,bg="white", width=50,font="Arial 10")
text1.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
Button(window, text="send",width=6,command=click).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
window.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder_name\testing.py", line 5, in click
    a = text1.get()
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your error says `get()` is missing required positional arguments, you need to specify the `start` and `end` of text selection from the text entered.

The parameters you need to pass to the `get()` method:

`text1.get('1.0', 'end-1c')`

Here `1.0` means start getting text from **first character of the first line** and `end-1c` means select text till the end and `-1c` means removing `1 character` from the end as a  newline `\n` character is added at the end of the text. In simple words it will select all the text you entered.

**The working code:**

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

def click():
    a = text1.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    print(a)

window = Tk()
window.title("TITLE PLACEHOLDER")
Label(window,text="Subject", bg="black",fg="white", font="Arial 10").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
text1 = ScrolledText(window,bg="white", width=50,font="Arial 10")
text1.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
Button(window, text="send",width=6,command=click).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
window.mainloop()
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Hope it helps!