# Taking multiple lines(domains names) with tkinter

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I'm trying to take in multiple domain names, almost like a column. I plan to iterate through all the domains to resolve them to IPs.

Snipped code so far below takes in one line and prints the IP as expected. I'm having difficulty taking multiple lines.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661854/how-to-create-a-multiline-entry-with-tkinter/9662139) suggestion for both `Text` and `ScrolledText` but I keep getting error:
`TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'`.
I have tried indexing the `get()` with `text_in.get('1.0', END))` but then the host does not resolve with error:
`socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`

```py
from tkinter import *
import socket

root = Tk()
root.title("Testing")

def open_CIDR():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("CIDR Converter")
    text_in = Entry(top, width=50)
    text_in.pack()
    def cidrClick():
        myLabel = Label(top, text=socket.gethostbyname(text_in.get()))
        myLabel.pack()
    cidrButton = Button(top, text="Resolve", command=cidrClick)
    cidrButton.pack()

button_cidr = Button(root, text="CIDR Converter", padx=40, pady=20, command=open_CIDR)
button_cidr.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `ScrolledText` from `tkinter.scrolledtext`. You can get the multi-line text with the `get()` method if you set the start and end point. If you need the complete text, you should use the `('1.0', END)` parameters.  You should split the got text on `\n` characters and you will get a list of hosts. The you should iterate throug on this list and create a label on the `top`.

**Complete fixed code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import socket

root = Tk()
root.title("Testing")

def open_CIDR():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("CIDR Converter")
    text_in = ScrolledText(top, width=50)
    text_in.pack()
    def cidrClick():
        for single_host in text_in.get('1.0', END).split("\n"):
            if not single_host:
                continue
            myLabel = Label(top, text=socket.gethostbyname(single_host))
            myLabel.pack()
    cidrButton = Button(top, text="Resolve", command=cidrClick)
    cidrButton.pack()

button_cidr = Button(root, text="CIDR Converter", padx=40, pady=20, command=open_CIDR)
button_cidr.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**GUI:**

[image: GUI]

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot for your help.